# sitecore 8.1 Launchpad brings HTTP 500 error and several icons are missing

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

I am installing Sitecore 8.1 with SIM and get several Javascript errors coming from ajax request returning HTTP 500 errors when open my launchpad. Looking in the developers tools shows the message:

http://sitecore81/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/786FBA3A4573445EA74504E3CA5E48C1/all?&dateGrouping=by-week&&dateFrom=26-07-2015&dateTo=26-10-2015&keyGrouping=collapsed

http://sitecore81/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/7A9A483F195D4F96AD88473CD6854C4F/all?&dateGrouping=by-week&&keyTop=5&keyOrderBy=visits-Asc&dateFrom=26-07-2015&dateTo=26-10-2015&keyGrouping=by-key

```
"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AnalyticsDataController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."
"at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
```

That results to several icons missing from Launchpad, for example FXM.

[image: link to screenshot]

When I do installation from *.exe file from SDN I am getting the same result.
Is there any way to fix that, or that's Sitecore bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, the reason for you missing FXM and other icons is because of installing Sitecore with your old license file. The page on SDN says:

*Sitecore 8.1 now requires a license with the “Sitecore.xDB” key to enable all features of the Experience Platform. If your license file does not contain this key, Sitecore will default to Experience Management (CMS-only) mode. Any customers or partners with a license to Experience Platform should contact their account manager or login to SPN if they are missing this key.*

That means **you have to [obtain license](http://spn.sitecore.net/default.aspx) for 8.1 that includes xDB** (if you need xDB and are going to use)
I have experience the same behaviour as well on multiple machines.
Without having correct license file you Sitecore instance turns into CMS-only mode (link).

But in any case, returning 500 (internal server) errors in console, is **not** correct way of doing things *(I have even submitted support ticket about that behaviour on previous week)*. That happens even in case you **explicitly** turn CMS-only mode in `Sitecore.xDB.config` file; so I think that is a bug.

Hope that answers your question!